# rails3 content_tag with static attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, content-tag

The following is being properly generated into HTML code

```
<%= content_tag(:span, (t 'hints.h'), :class => "has-tip", :title => (t 'hints.s') ) %>
```

But I am trying to generate

```
<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" title="title bla bla">translated h</span>
```

and have found no way to generate these span attributes `data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true"`  They cannot be part of the options hash given one has only a name... and the second one has a dash which impedes from defining it as a symbol :aria-haspopup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you use the following:

`content_tag(:span, t('hints.h'), :class => 'has-tip', :title => t('hints.s'), :'aria-haspopup' => true, :'data-tooltip' => '')`

Note that you can use the dash character in symbols if you enclose them in quotes.

The data attribute you could also specify as nested hash like `:data => {:tooltip => ''}` instead of `:'data-tooltip' => ''`, use whatever you prefer.

As for the boolean attribute `data-tooltip`, setting the value to an empty string is as good as omitting it (and your best option with Rails 3 ;)). See also:

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes

Comment: Learned something new about boolean attributes, they can be stated in three ways, including the empty string. And, logically, omitting it means `false`...